# Full file path with drive letter

Tags: windows, driver, kernel-mode, filter-driver

I am a beginner in driver development. I am developing a filter driver(Kernel Mode).
I want to get the full path of every file which is opened.
I have a **file object and an IRP**.
I am using **&pFileObject->fileName** to display the path. It shows the complete path but dose not show drive letter. 
Kindly provide a kernel level routine which tells the **drive letter**. 
below is the code

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "drv_common.h"
#include "ntddk.h"
#include "FsFilter.h"


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    ////////
// PassThrough IRP Handler

NTSTATUS FsFilterDispatchPassThrough( __in PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, __in PIRP Irp )
{
    PFSFILTER_DEVICE_EXTENSION pDevExt = (PFSFILTER_DEVICE_EXTENSION)DeviceObject-    >DeviceExtension;

    IoSkipCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);
    return IoCallDriver(pDevExt->AttachedToDeviceObject, Irp);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    ////////
// IRP_MJ_CREATE IRP Handler

NTSTATUS FsFilterDispatchCreate(
    __in PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject,
    __in PIRP           Irp
    )
{
    PFILE_OBJECT pFileObject = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp)->FileObject;

    DbgPrint("%wZ\n", &pFileObject->FileName);

    return FsFilterDispatchPassThrough(DeviceObject, Irp);
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a not a "plz give me teh codez" website. You need to explain what you've tried, show some actual code, and explain where it goes wrong. People are much more willing to help if you demonstrate that you've put some effort into solving the problem yourself.

Comment: Cody i have edited my question now can you help me

Comment: Cody I thougth only specifying routine will be enough...

Comment: Try `IoVolumeDeviceToDosName` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550422(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks sergmat for help..On using this routine VM crashes.. What could br its reason??

Answer (score 1):

As @sergmat suggested you can use `IoVolumeDeviceToDosName` routine to get the volume name. But be sure that you call that route only at `PASSIVE_LEVEL`, which might be what you are experiencing.

Also, using `pFileObject->FileName` in dispatch routine is not recommended. The memory may come from paged pool which is not accessible in `DISPATCH_LEVEL` or higher.